# remove single tick line

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I want to remove a single tick line (namely the first, on the spine's edge) but keep its label. I remember something like that:
`ax.get_xticklines()[0].set_markersize(0)`

worked earlier, now not. In general, I can remove all or nothing.

Also,

```
for line in ax.get_xticklines():
   line.set_markersize(0)
```

removes all ticks, but:

```
k = 0
for line in ax.get_xticklines():
    if k ==0:    
       line.set_markersize(0)
       k+=1
```

ignores condition and keeps all ticks, no error or warning.
matplotlib version 3.5.3

Comment: it looks like ax.get_xticklines()[1].set_markersize(0) works. Removing ticks requires odd numbers, 1 to first, 3 to second etc. No idea why?